# Grab file with chrome extension before upload

Tags: forms, file, file-upload, google-chrome-extension

using my chrome extension i would like to grab a file(and maybe change it) before it gets uploaded to a website. Particularly from  file-inputs.
Put another way if i select a file with an input[type=file] i want my chrome extension to interrupt any submit and take the file. Then my extension applies its magic to the file and after that the file may be submitted/uploaded.
How can i approach this?

On problem occurs with the file path. If i grab the vaule of a file-input it always changes the actual path to " C:\fakepath\" due to HTML5 standard and compatibility issues.
How can i access the file then? Maybe it is saved temporarily in some chrome storage?

EDIT:
Well, i managed to read the file selected in the file input like this:

```
var file;
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();      
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        console.log(event.target.result);  //contains the file data
        //maybe change data and use filewriter  

    };      
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

Now i would like to use a FileWriter to write to e.target.files[0]

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/
but i am not able to create a proper FileWriter.

It is not necessary to write to the original file on the disk - might not even possible - but i need to change the data that is used to upload in the corresponding file-input form field.

Answer (score 6):

There's no defined API for a Chrome extension to intercept the payload of a request ([work in progress](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/notifications-of-web-request-and-navigation#TOC-Accessing-request-and-response-bodi)).

That being said, you can use a [Content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to add an event listener which:

1. Cancels the normal form submission.
2. Reads the file as an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) using the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) API.
3. Modify the resulting `ArrayBuffer` after wrapping it in a [view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView).
4. Create a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob) from the modified data.
5. Reconstruct the form by creating a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) instance, then use the [`.append(name, value[, filename])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#append%28%29) method.
   Note: In the example below, I did **not** include the form reconstruction method. I only included the file upload part. There are two approaches to reconstruct the form:

   1. Write a method which is specific to your form.
   2. Write a general form-parsing method, which takes care of nameless/disabled/unchecked/... elements. If you want to take this route, have a look at the [W3 specification for the Form submission algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm).
6. Submit the data [using `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest). Note: If you're running this code in the context of your Chrome extension, don't forget to explicitly whitelist the URL at the [`permissions` section in the manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions).

Here's an example of the implementation:

```
// Reference to the form:
var form = document.forms["uploadForm"];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // Cancel submission

    var fileInput = form.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    if (!file) return; // No file selected

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        var arraybuffer = fileReader.result;
        // To manipulate an arraybuffer, wrap it in a view:
        var view = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        view[0] = 0; // For example, change the first byte to a NULL-byte

        // Create an object which is suitable for use with FormData
        var blob = new Blob([view], {type: file.type});

        // Now, the form reconstruction + upload part:
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(fileInput.name, blob, file.name);
        // ... handle remainder of the form ...

        // Now, submit the form
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', form.action);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            // Do something. For example:
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log(xhr); // Aw. Error. Log xhr object for debugging
        }
        xhr.send(formData);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

Comment: If i use "form.addEventListener('submit'..." in my extension and use FormData+xhr to send the form, will that overwrite or corrupt submit handlers on the website (e.g. for form validation)?

Comment: @user1547097 No, `addEventListener` **adds** an event listener. It does not overwrite previously defined event listeners (inline: `<form onsubmit="..">`, expando (JS): `form.onsubmit = ...`, previously added event listeners: `form.addEventListener('submit', ...)`).

Comment: Well yes, but how to handle this on a website?: `function foonsubmit (that) {
 $('[name="foo"]').val(2);
 that.submit();
}` .....`<form onsubmit=foonsubmit(this);` .... that will submit the form even if i use `ev.preventDefault();`in the content script

Comment: @user1547097 If you *really* want to get rid off the inline event, use `form.remoteAttribute('onsubmit');` or `form.onsubmit = null`: http://jsfiddle.net/VfU3q/.

Comment: That's the point. I do NOT want to get rid of those event since my extension should not corrupt a website(form validation etc.) .. Again: i "only" want to edit a fileupload on the fly without changing anything in the rest of the form.

Comment: @user1547097 Another option is to void the `submit` method of the form (of course, after storing a reference to the original handler): http://jsfiddle.net/VfU3q/1/. Then, `addEventListener('submit', ...)` will run as expected. Note: The form itself is **not** submitted, **you reconstruct the form** in the event listener, then **submit that form using XHR2**. The page won't unload, but if you wish, you *can* change the URL using `history.pushState` and replace the document by DOM manipulation (which is even easier when `xhr.responseType='document'` is available).

Comment: Well in that case there will occur problems if the website handles the form submission in that submit method and not using a submit button....

Comment: @user1547097 The event bound using `addEventListener` are sequentially executed (order depends on the time of definition). Since your extension binds the event in the end, all of the page's "form-modifying/validating" stuff have already been executed. When the form is invalid, the page's script ought call `event.stopPropagation();`. To get back at your comment: The `onsubmit` event is still fired. But calls to the direct `submit()` are ignored.

Comment: Is there no way to e.g. read the selected file then copy it into html5 storage with write permission then edit it(possible up to here) and after that _change the file input (of the existing form) to point its filehandler to the file in html5 storage_?

Comment: @user1547097 No, the `files` property of the `<input type=file>` element is **read-only**.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the old file-in put and create a new one in JS with same attributes but with my modified blob?

Comment: Well seems as if my content script is not able to modify the .submit ... `$('form')[0].submit = function(){};` works in the website and disables any submit, but executed in the content script it has no effect on the websites submit...

Comment: @user1547097 Possibly caused by the fact that content scripts only have access to the *DOM* of a page. The solution is thoroughly explained at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879).

Comment: Why not simply use the existing form?  var newFormData = new FormData(someFormElement);  Then append the file; no need to rebuild the entire form first.

Comment: @BrianFreud The `formData` object has an `.append` method, but no `.remove` option. The goal is to replace `type=file` elements. One can move the input type=file element, then use the `FormData` constructor. That may result in side effects though (such as a broken lay-out). One can also remove the `name` attribute of the element. And don't even try to use `someFormElement.cloneNode(true);`, because the user-defined values are not cloned.