# Is it possible to call one custom keyword function from another Custom keywords from katalon Automation Tool?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to call method from one custom keywords to another Custom keywords functions

But i am getting below error,

> 05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [START] - Start action :
>   mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation.textfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [INFO] - Finding Test Object with id 'Object
>   Repository/HelpDeskModule/Master/Team/Page_eFACiLiTY/input_Txt_Code'
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [ERROR] - No such property: CustomKeywords
>   for class: mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [END] - End action :
>   mandatoryfield_Validation.Mandatoryfieldvalidation.textfieldvalidation
>   05-30-2018 02:59:02 PM - [ERROR] - Test
>   Cases/HelpDeskModule/Master/Team_/Team FAILED because (of) Variable
>   'CustomKeywords' is not defined for test case.

please find the code below

```
public class Mandatoryfieldvalidation {
//<!--Initializing object-->

private static Connection connection = null;
private static  String columntype;
private static int num;
private static int datatypevalue
def driver = DF.getWebDriver()
KeywordLogger logger = new KeywordLogger()
JavascriptExecutor js = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
//Method for validating textfield
@Keyword
def void textfieldvalidation()
{
CustomKeywords.'alerthandling.verifyalertpresent.verifyalert'()

}
}
```

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: not error, file not created

Comment: @fateme i need to create one folder and upload a file inside a created folder but in starting itself unable to proceed

Comment: In server?? chrome?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538377/how-can-i-create-new-folder-file-with-javascript