# How long does a Blob file created in Google Chrome Exist?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blob

Part of a Google Chrome Extension I am working on has this existing JavaScript below for creating a Blog file from a screenshot image...

```
    getBlob = function(canvas) {
        // standard dataURI can be too big, let's blob instead
        // http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227#c27

        var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL(),
            // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
            // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]),
            // separate out the mime component
            mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0],
            // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
            ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length),
            ia = new Uint8Array(ab),
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
    },

    saveBlob = function(blob, filename, callback, errback) {
        var onWriteEnd = function() {
            // Return the name of the file that now contains the blob.
            callback('filesystem:chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id + '/temporary/' + filename);
        };

        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs){
            fs.root.getFile(filename, {create:true}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.onwriteend = onWriteEnd;
                    fileWriter.write(blob);
                }, errback);
            }, errback);
        }, errback);
    },
```

Looking at `saveBlob(blob, filename, callback, errback)` above.  How long would a file created this way exist?  Does it disappear when the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2):

The file would exist until directly deleted by user or `Clear browsing data` is used at `settings`; though there is no guarantee of persistence.

[4.4.1.2 Constants](https://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html#constants)

> `TEMPORARY` of type `unsigned short` Used for storage with no
>   guarantee of persistence.

See also [Temporary storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage?csw=1#temporary)

Comment: I actually just came across this `Data stored using TEMPORARY can be removed at the browser's discretion (for example if more space is needed).` and I see it called here `window.webkitRequestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024*1024,)`

Comment: Yes. That is another way a file could be removed from filesystem. You can check if file exists in `FileSystem` using  `DevTools` -> `Experiments` -> check `FileSystem inspection` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098129/how-to-write-in-file-user-directory-using-javascript/

Comment: @JasonDavis Try visiting plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EVVNYYUvHiM545T06kMC?p=preview , closing chrome, re-launching chrome then at `terminal` `$ ~/.config/chrome/Default/File\ System` , then  `$ ls` . The numerical directories listed should contain the files saved to `FileSystem`

Comment: @JasonDavis Clearing browsing data also delete file in `FileSystem`

Comment: @ZigMandel In the original form, when I downvoted, it was incorrect and very short without any references.