# Is there a way to set a cookie using JS and force a dynamic element reliant on the cookie to update without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, cookies, geolocation, setcookie

apologies if the title question is confusing, but I'm not entirely sure how to ask or phrase this. Basically, I want a button to trigger (it opens a popup) on page load—easy enough.

*However*, the button is a "Find a Location" thing, so upon a user's first-time (or cookie-less) visit, they see that button. If the user clicks it and inputs their location info, they get redirected to a page, and the button changes to one displaying their location, and the popup content also changes; the button gets fed a stored cookie with the location info, which is how the content updates.

I need to figure out a way to get this location info, via this cookie, injected on page load without the user having to enter their information at all, OR refreshing/navigating away from the page.

Right now, I have a function written to set the cookie upon load, and then automatically trigger the popup, *but* the button does not automatically update via the manual cookie setting unless the user reloads the page. I need everything to happen in one seamless motion. Is this feasible, or no?

I need to do this via Javascript, if it is even possible—no other methods, please. Also, this is not something I can do via the site's back end or some CMS either.

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing that automatically links cookies to the code that depends on them. You'll need to find the code that cares about the cookie and call it again explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to use cookies.

You can use `localStorage` or `navigator.storage.getDirectory()` to achieve the requirement. On document load if the string or directory exists, get the data, else create the string or directory and files and write the data.

For example, here's how I fetch a an external library once, if the file is not set in `navigator.storage`, else I load an Ecmascript Module from the file stored in `navigator.storage`:

```
const dir = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();
const entries = await Array.fromAsync(dir.keys());
let handle;
if (!entries.includes("lames.js")) {
  handle = await dir.getFileHandle("lame.js", {
    create: true,
  });
  await new Blob([await (await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/master/native_messaging/capture_system_audio/lame.min.js", )).arrayBuffer(), ], {
    type: "text/javascript",
  }).stream().pipeTo(await handle.createWritable());
} else {
  handle = await dir.getFileHandle("lame.js", {
    create: false,
  });
}
const file = await handle.getFile();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
const {
  lamejs
} = await import(url);
this.mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(2, 44100, 192);
```

Note, technically it is possible to read `localStorage` and the data stored in `navigator.storage`, and when `webkitRequestFileSystem` is used from the browser configuration file, see [How to write into a file (in user directory) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098618/2801559).

Comment: i think you could provide a minimal example though. Just setting a cookie and then using onload.

Comment: @Minsky I would not set a cookie. I would write the arbitrary data directly to `navigator.storage.getDirectory()`, thereafter I can get the data from any tab or window on that origin. We can take the task a step further and write the data to the users' filesystem, then retrieve from there.

Comment: i don't like overly complex code for a simple task, but if that's a solution for OP then great.

Comment: _"overly complex code"_ That's solely a matter of opinion and perception.

Comment: @guest271314 – This would be acceptable IF I could theoretically just set and set a storage variable. Let's just say that this is for a client's website and there is a specific JSON object cookie that I must use for this project. I do not believe their other code will trigger the location update for the button with anything but this cookie. Could you possibly still share how this could be done with cookies?

Comment: Depends on how the cookies are set. Some cookies can't be read by JavaScript in the browser - not without using means that are not ordinarily exposed in the browser, such as HTTP only cookies. However you set the data you basically can use the same pattern to set and read the data.