# Is there any reliable way to capture file upload event in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my content script, I want to monitor which file a is getting uploaded to a web application.

I monitor "change" event for any "input:file" element. It works on any site (such as Gmail) that uses "input:file".

However sites like imgur, use SWFUpload mechanism. I tried to capture "fileQueued" event on element that I suspected to be swfupload. But that did not work.

- How can I capture file upload event for sites that use swfupload?
- Are there any other plugins that manage file uploading that I would need to take care in my content script?
- Is there any generic mechanism to tackle this problem?

(I am aware of drag-n-drop mechanism, but I have not handled that case so far.
I have also read following relevant question on SO:

[Grab file with chrome extension before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621592/grab-file-with-chrome-extension-before-upload))

Comment: Common file upload methods would be drag and drop/file api (html5), background iframe, flash uploader, silverlight uploader. You'll probably have issues detecting the last three.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth your time to experiment with the [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API; it appears that the onBeforeRequest event contains info about file uploads. It's a complex API with extra parameters to addListener; read the docs thoroughly.

Comment: Except that it doesn't include requests from plugins such as Flash.

Comment: I'd call that a bug - Firefox lets its extensions intercept plugin-originated Web requests, and I don't see why Chrome couldn't, too. Is there anything about this on the Chromium bug tracker?