# capture file upload/download event in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

To capture download Event using a chrome extension, I can use in my background.js the event chrome.downloads.onCreate.. can I have an example for that I couldn't find an example in the documentation ?

also, to capture Upload Event, As I read here, [Is there any reliable way to capture file upload event in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897925/is-there-any-reliable-way-to-capture-file-upload-event-in-a-chrome-extension)

I can use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest event but How? any example of code would be very helpful...

I managed to capture Upload Event from the DOM using by capturing input[type='file'] onChange Event, but that's not very efficient. I need to capture web requests and check for existance of a file there.

Thanks

```
var slctList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");
for(i=0;i<slctList.length;i++){

    slctList[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
               var files = e.files;
               var file = files[0];
               console.log(file.name);

            });
}
```

Comment: I can't check if the content of the request is a file?

Comment: When we upload a file usually there is a little lable in bottom left which indicates the percentage of uploading task ..

Comment: Sorry, I think you miss understood my question.

Comment: I don't need the file path, I need to detect if the browser is uploading or downloading a file

Comment: There's no separate event in the extensions API so you'll have to use the content script. You're saying it's inefficient, but why specifically?

Comment: Because this code is detecting Change event of input[type=file] ..

Comment: Not necessarily uploading file

Comment: Well, you'll have to be creative e.g. listen also on `submit` event, maybe also intercept XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send in a [page script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) (and similarly for `fetch`).

Comment: can you please see if this link will help .?
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-UploadData

Comment: Maybe, but judging by the [description](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-requestBody-raw) it's only for direct upload via PUT or POST method outside of forms - apparently this will better handle the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send case I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please write a code of how to use this API..