# JS : Upload automatically a file to a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm programing a bot which do some tests on the UI of an application developed with AngularJS.
To do that, I use PhantomJS BUT, I'm blocked... In fact, I must upload a .csv file in order to validate the form, but I cannot for the moment. I have no idea how resolve this problem.

I have found this : `page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');`
BUT, other problem... I use Mocha for testing and my tests are injected into the code of the app. So, i don't know how get the page object.

A simple plan of my architecture :

## launcher.js

```
Initialize PhantomJS
page.open() {
    page.evaluate() {
        page.injectJs(all my tests);
    }
}
```

## test_1.js

```
describe...
it('should works', ...) {
    Fill form 
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can't fill a fileinput from javascript ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739946/chrome-create-file-input-from-blob-with-javascript)).

What are you testing exactly? If you are testing the server part, you can use an [XMLHttpRequest and FormData to upload a Blob object as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621592/grab-file-with-chrome-extension-before-upload/11628694#11628694). If you are writing end-to-end tests, you could try [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/). If you do UI tests, you will have to mock the network part of it, possibly by compiling separate javascript files for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I followed "my tests are injected into the code of the app". Do you mean to say tests are within the same project as your application? If so, then thats a very common setup. You need to have your server running and then run tests against the running server

```
 var webpage = require('webpage') 
    describe("test suite", function() {
       it("test upload", function(done) {
             console.log('Loading a web page');
             var page = webpage.create();
             var url = 'http://your.server';
             page.open(url, function (status) {
                //Page is loaded!
                page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
                phantom.exit(done);
            });
       });
    });
```